# consistent text-height using css

Tags: google-chrome, dom, render, css

In a big testsuite I'm testing how layout is interpreted in detail and have found that Google Chrome on Mac and Linux calculates the size of the text area differently, see this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/AndrasMadsen/Cspcf/

For your information I can tell that mac render the `<span>` box as:

```
{
  "top": 8,
  "bottom": 25,
  "left": 8,
  "right": 84,
  "width": 76,
  "height": 17
}
```

while Linux render it as:

```
{
  "top": 8,
  "bottom": 26,
  "left": 8,
  "right": 84,
  "width": 76,
  "height": 18
}
```

I could of cause make the test more flexible, but since the result is to be analyzed later by a computer, it's quite important to get box size the consistent.

It is also worth noticing that the solution only need to run on the latest version of Google Chrome and if changing the font-family solves it then thats fine. But I would like to avoid adding a bunch of custom CSS properties in order to get close to the real world, where I'm not in control of the CSS. However in this testsuite I am in control of the CSS, so it is acceptable.

Comment: The font itself is dictating the size of the span.  The font used on each OS in question would have to be *identical* in every aspect in order for them to be the same.

Comment: Agreed. The web world is quite different than the print world.

Comment: Is there then a font there is identical on every OS (it don't have to pretty) ?

Answer (score 0):

When you do not specify `line-height`, browsers will apply their defaults, which are supposed to depend on the font. Setting `line-height` does not guarantee that all browsers use the same height for line boxes, but it’s a start.

Comment: How is this going to help?  There's nothing you can do in CSS that will resolve the fact that the font-face used on one OS has slightly taller or narrower glyphs than another, nor can you enforce consistent leading.  Adjusting line-height is about as useful as adjusting font-size:  you can do it, but it won't get you pixel perfect rendering in every browser.

Comment: @cimmanon, it helps because the question was about “text-height” and “box size”, not about height or width of glyphs.

Comment: This didn't work, see http://jsfiddle.net/AndrasMadsen/MRkVm/3/. On MAC the height is `17px` and on Linux it is `18px`.

Comment: The vertical sizing of non-replaced inline elements is browser-dependent (and may well exceed the `line-height` value set on then, as the experiment shows). If you use a block element, or set `span { display: block }`, the `line-height` value sets the minimal height of line boxes.